# Is it reasonable to view $P(Y|X_1, X_2, X_3)$ as 3 coin flips?

Tags: distributions, estimation

This [CMU Machine Learning Course](https://youtu.be/tpmdcJYnAyQ?t=1307) gives a formula to compute the number of params in an estimation.

$2^n$ for the distribution $P(Y|X_1, X_2, ... X_n)$

[image]

consider 3 boolean RVs, is it reasonable to viewed $P(Y|X_1, X_2, X_3)$ as 3 coin flips? if yes, what does each param do?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $Y$ is binary. The parameters are as follows:

\begin{align*}
\pi_1 &\equiv \Pr(Y=1\mid X_1=0, X_2=0, X_3=0), \\
\pi_2 &\equiv \Pr(Y=1\mid X_1=0, X_2=0, X_3=1), \\
\pi_3 &\equiv \Pr(Y=1\mid X_1=0, X_2=1, X_3=0), \\
&\vdots \\
\pi_8 &\equiv \Pr(Y=1\mid X_1=1, X_2=1, X_3=1).
\end{align*}

So the parameters are the success probabilities under each combination of coin flips.
A nonprametric estimator slices the sample up into these eight subsamples and computes the average of $Y$ in each subsample to get $\hat\pi_1, \ldots, \hat\pi_8$.